# Releasing NSMutableArray in dealloc causes the app to crash

Tags: ios, memory-management, memory-leaks, nsmutablearray

I have a `UIView` which holds a `UITableView`. This table is being populated by an `NSMutableArray`.

I initialized both the array and the table in the UIView's `initWithFrame:` method.

```
- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
{
  self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
  if (self)
  {
    bookTable = [[UITableView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(100, 108, 260, 535)];
    bookArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init]; //this array will be populated later

    //other codes
  }
  return self;
}
```

I release them in `dealloc`:

```
- (void)dealloc
{
   [bookTable release];      
   [bookArray release];

   [super dealloc];
}
```

The problem is when the app crashes in `dealloc`. It produces the error: `[CALayer release]: message sent to deallocated instance 0x82db660`

I looked everywhere in my code and I'm sure that I didn't overreleased anything. I decided to remove the `[bookArray release]` in `dealloc`, and it stopped crashing. I ran the `Analyze` and it doesn't give me any potential leaks.

Can anyone explain to me why releasing the array in dealloc causes the crash?

**NOTE:** 
Both the table and the array are instance variables of the view.

**EDIT:**
Code for populating the array:

```
NSString *sql = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"SELECT BookName FROM books WHERE UserID=%d", userId];
booksArray = [sqlite executeQuery:sql];
```

Please note that I am using a sql wrapper.

Comment: Just make sure you haven't enabled ARC for the project.

Comment: If ARC was enabled the compiler wouldn't allow the use of [super dealloc]...

Comment: Could you provide the code you use to populate the array?

Comment: @Tobi I added the code above.

Comment: @AnnaFortuna how do you add elements to `bookArray`?

Comment: @mayuur Oops! Thans for pointing it out. It should be bookArray instead of pagesAndNotes.

Comment: share the code of adding elements to the array as suggested my @mayuur

Comment: please post executeQuery method. I think you are returning something like `return [element autorelease];`

Comment: @MidhunMP actually the `executeQuery` method returns `[array release]`.

Answer (score 0):

Problem is here only, I assume.

```
booksArray = [sqlite executeQuery:sql];
```

the `executeQuery` method might be returning an autoreleased NSMutableArray or something like this might be written inside `executeQuery`

```
NSMutableArray* tempArray = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:0];
```

If its like this, it should already be in autoreleased mode, hence no `release` in `dealloc` method.

**UPDATE**

Also, as0sign property to the array.

```
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSMutableArray* booksArray;
```

And then, wherever you use it, use it as `self.booksArray`

```
self.booksArray = [sqlite executeQuery:sql];
```

This way, it would be proper memory management and then release the array in dealloc.

Comment: Hi. The method `executeQuery` returns this: `[array release];`.

Comment: change it to `[array autorelease];`

Comment: I have another question. If I call removeAllObjects, will it reduce the retain count of the array?

Comment: No, but it reduces the retain count of the objects in the array at this point.

Answer (score 0):

Here lies the problem

```
booksArray = [sqlite executeQuery:sql];
```

The array returned by the `sqlite` is an autoreleased object. You must either retain it or remove release from `dealloc'.

```
booksArray = [[sqlite executeQuery:sql] retain];
```

Since it is autoreleased object, releasing it in dealloc results in crash when system also tries to `release` it.

And do remove the array initialization in `init` method, it's redundant.

Comment: I did this instead: `booksArray = [[sqliteArray valueForKey:@"Books"]retain];`, yet it still crashes.

Comment: Okay now I am guessing but remove the retain and remove the `release` call in dealloc. It won't be a memory leak. try instruments to confirm

Comment: It leaked. First, since the array was autoreleased. Then something like `NSFireDelayedPerform` released the array as well. So when my table is trying to access the content of the array, it crashes.

Comment: if the problem persists, share the whole .m and .h files using https://gist.github.com/

Answer (score 0):

1. Change the return statement of your `executeQuery` method like `[array autorelease]`
2. Replace `booksArray = [sqlite executeQuery:sql];` by `booksArray = [[sqlite executeQuery:sql] retain];`

If you wrote `property` for the `booksArray` like `@property(nonatomic, retain) NSMutableArray *bookArray;` then you can replace **step 2** by `self.bookArray = [sqlite executeQuery:sql];`

Your issue is you are returning an released object from the `executeQuery` method (You mentioned it on your comment). That's why you are getting the error

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to create a property for the booksArray like this:

```
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSMutableArray *bookArray;
```

An when you populate it try this code:

```
self.bookArray = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:[sqlite executeQuery:sql]];
```

That'll create an autoreleased copy of the returned array which is then "auto"-retained by the property.

Of course you should make sure, that the array return by [sqlite executeQuery:sql] is autoreleased.